# Composition of function pair

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am very new to OCaml and I am currently trying to solve some exercises. While doing so I stumbled over the following problem:

```
let compose_pair (p:(('b -> 'c) * ('a -> 'b))) : 'a -> 'c =
```

The goal is to complete the function such that it composes the two functions of the pair in sequence.

My problem is that, as far as I understand, the return type of this function should again be a function and I don't really know how to achieve that.

My attempt would be something like

```
(fst p) (snd p)
```

which happens to just return something of type `'c` if I understood this right.

Does anyone know how to solve this? i would be very thankful for some tips or hints.

My current try is this:

```
let compose_pair (p:(('b -> 'c) * ('a -> 'b))) : 'a -> 'c = 
  fun x -> fst p (snd p x)
```

Comment: did you try your code in the interpreter? did you have previous exercises where you had to define a function?

Comment: @coredump The part of the function from my question was already given in the exercise. But yes there were other functions where I already defined functions.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing a function that takes a pair:

```
fun pair -> ...
```

and returns a function, which takes some value:

```
fun pair -> (fun value -> ...)
```

The return value in the inner function is the composition of the functions stored in the pair.

Answer (score 1):

Your function, as quoted below, appears to work quite well.

> ```
> let compose_pair (p:(('b -> 'c) * ('a -> 'b))) : 'a -> 'c = 
>   fun x -> fst p (snd p x)
> ```

```
# let compose_pair (p:(('b -> 'c) * ('a -> 'b))) : 'a -> 'c = 
  fun x -> fst p (snd p x)  ;;
val compose_pair : ('b -> 'c) * ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'c = <fun>
# let f = compose_pair ((fun x -> x + 1), (fun x -> x * 2));;
val f : int -> int = <fun>
# f 3;;
- : int = 7
```

However, it can be cleaned up. You can pattern match a tuple argument to a function directly, rather than calling `fst` and `snd`.

```
let compose_pair (f, g) = ...
```

You can then produce a function which takes an argument and applies it to these functions.

```
let compose_pair (f, g) = 
  fun x -> f (g x)
```

But we can simplify this further, because `let f a b c = ...` is the same as writing `let f = fun a -> fun b -> fun c -> ...`.

```
let compose_pair (f, g) x = f (g x)
```

Or as an alternative, using the `|>` operator, which allows this to read as `x` passed to `g` and the result of that passed to `f`.

```
let compose_pair (f, g) x = x |> g |> f
```